# How to Auto Login and Redirect After Registration in yii?

Tags: php, session, yii

When I use redirect function after auto login this error occur:

session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed

Can anyone hep me?

```
<?php
public function actionRegister()
{
    $model = new UserProfileForm;

    $this->performAjaxValidation($model,'userProfile-form');

    if(isset($_POST['UserProfileForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['UserProfileForm'];
        if ($model->save()) 
        {
            $u = new LoginForm;
            $u->username = $model->username;
            $u->password = $model->password;
            $u->login();

            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
    }
    $this->render('register',array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

?>

Comment: You have this problem with Firefox?

Comment: @msoa yes I have this problem with Firefox !

Answer (score 2):

The following works.

```
if($model->save()){            

    $identity=new UserIdentity($model->username,$model->password);
    $identity->authenticate();
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity);

    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);                
}
```

PS: `$model->save()` runs `$model->validate()` so you are repeating yourself